# Plugin: extend intellij php syntax highlighting

Tags: php, intellij-plugin

Currently, php plugin/implementation in intellij platform allows to register own parser for phpdoc tags. (`PhpDocTagParserRegistry.register("@property", new PhpDocPropertyTagParser());`). This allows to create own psi structures for certaing tags.

Is there any way that would allow to extend php highlighter (add a layer) that could highlight own phpdoc tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an implementation of com.intellij.lang.annotation.Annotator to extend syntax highlighting for any language in IntelliJ IDEA.

For every element which you need to highlight, you need to call `AnnotationHolder.createInfoAnnotation()`, and then call `setTextAttributes()` on the returned `Annotation` object.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please, could you be more specific? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Annotator I can't find a way how to make syntax highlighting through Annotator. I do not want a "warning underline".

Comment: One connected small question: is there any way how to preview annotator coloring in settings color page?

Comment: You can provide your own color settings page with your own preview text. Previewing the highlighting of your annotator in the PHP page isn't possible.